# Sign certificate only with csr

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, csr

i have client which he is having csr file, but I need to generate certificate from that csr file. He is the owner of the privatekey but he won't send it. Can someone tell me what was the procedure, because I was used to use easy-rsa sign-req with that csr, but seems it's not possible.

The certificate then will be used in nginx config (as client side verification certificate) where I will auth his requests to the server.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want a self-signed certificate, i.e. a certificate which is issued by itself, then the client should create it themselves using their private key - which the client should keep private (hence the name). If you want instead to have your own CA where you can sign the clients CSR with your own root CA, then you need to have the infrastructure for such a PKI in place. Depending on the security, professionality and usability this might be from some open source scripts up to commercial products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think the CA solution sounds good for me, this is what I've tried to achieve with easy-rsa, but I've stuck on part where I should use those rootCA? should I integrate with my server certificate on nginx , or I should use commercial SSL chain for nginx?

Comment: Still not clear. Your nginx certificate is unrelated to creating a certificate from the clients csr  with your own CA. And using a commercial CA can not be mixed with using your own CA. If you want a certificate signed by a commercial CA you need to give the CA to this commercial CA instead.

Comment: But if i do with own CA, can be this certificate attached with the csr and key that client has created?

Comment: The point of the CSR is that a CA (no matter if own CA or public) can issue a certificate based on this which contains the public key contained in the CSR. There is nothing "attached" though - it is inside. I recommend that you make yourself familiar first with what CSR and certificates are in the first place before working with these.